# How would I make the limit based if a user is logged in or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rate-limiting

I am trying to use express and express-rate-limit to limit anonymous users download limit, the catch is that if the user object sent with the request is true, I want to disable the limit. How would I go about doing it? This is a code snippet:

```
const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
    max: if (user) { return 0 } else { return 10 }, //THIS IS THE LINE I NEED HELP WITH
    standardHeaders: true, // Return rate limit info in the `RateLimit-*` headers
    legacyHeaders: false, // Disable the `X-RateLimit-*` headers
})
app.use('/link', limiter)
app.post("/link", async (req, res) => {
  const premiumLink = req.body.downloadLink;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const user = req.body.user;
//do function here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the express-rate-limit documentation, `max` can be either a number or a function.

> max: number | function
>
> The maximum number of connections to allow during the window before
> rate limiting the client.
>
> Can be the limit itself as a number or a (sync/async) function that
> accepts the Express request and response objects and then returns a
> number.

Here is an example also provided in the documentation:

```
const isPremium = async (user) => {
    // ...
}

const limiter = rateLimit({
    // ...
    max: async (request, response) => {
        if (await isPremium(request.user)) return 10
        else return 5
    },
})
```

EDIT:

To better answer, your question, here is how you can achieve what you want to do:

```
const limiter = rateLimit({
        // ...
        max: async (request, response) => {
            if (request.body.user) return 0
            else return 10
        },
    })
```